# trouble with import query to database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this query and I tried to import it to phpmyadmin. Can you tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dp_confirms`;
CREATE TABLE `dp_confirms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `newuser` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newpass` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `newanswer` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `newmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `newfname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newlname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newcompany` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `newregnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newdrvnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newaddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `newcity` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `newcountry` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `newstate` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newzip` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newphone` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `newfax` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `sponsor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `confirm` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `cdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newuser` (`newuser`),
  KEY `newmail` (`newmail`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Error I get:
    MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newuser` (`newuser`),
  K' at line 22
```

Comment: Ask yourself what timestamp(14) means. Is it valid?

Comment: You can no longer specify the length of a timestamp column. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128330/sql-error-version-5-5-15

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the length for a timestamp such as `timestamp(14)` was deprecated in MySQL 5.1, and is no longer supported from MySQL 5.5.

This is easily fixed by removing the length specification:

```
`cdate` timestamp NOT NULL,
```